# How to value delivery another class on android?

Tags: java, android

I want when I button click, show dialog.

but I multiple button click, show overlap dialog (multiple dialog)

so,I  use count on `AAA.class`

```
if (count == 0) {
    dialog.show();
    count ++;
}
```

my `BBB.class` is dialog button setOnClickListener.

```
positiveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        dismiss();
     }
});
```

I want when click positiveBtn, count value 0.

first. `AAA.class` is abstract interface class.

how to from `BBB.class` count value delivery another class on android?

thanks.

Comment: post your class AAA and BBB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.  Instead, disable the button (using setEnabled(false)) on the button when clicked.  Then re-enable it when the dialog is dismissed.